# How to manage different config environments in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I'd like to have a few environments, let's say `development`, `production`, `test`. These environments should be independent and use their own set of config parameters, e.g. for DB, SERVER_PORT, USER etc.
They should not be in the code base, so I think they should be different .env files. That's to say, I should be able to load different .env files depending on what environment is active. Also, it's not clear where I have to set that env switcher.

Maybe it should be a single .env file that has the NODE_ENV parameter, that param can be set to any of the above-mentioned values, be that development, production or test. And depending on the value of this parameter a necessary set of config parameters gets automatically loaded.

I've read the documentation, it seems a little confusing to me at the moment.

Seems like there should be some config factory.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Assuming you have the following config files in the root of the project: `env.development`, `env.staging`, `env.test`

Here is how I would implement it:

In the `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: !ENV ? '.env' : `.env.${ENV}`,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Inspired by this solution: https://github.com/nestjsx/nestjs-config#using-different-env-files

Comment: I like this approach better over all other. But where do you set process.env.NODE_ENV. In Package.json?

Comment: @KrishnanSriram  "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch" is one approach.

Comment: @ChristianGroleau Using cross-env will ensure that the env variable is set for all OS (windows, linux).

Comment: console.log('ENV', ENV); = ENV undefined

Comment: This answer is incomplete. It has to be accompanied with how one will specifiy the NODE_ENV. Because that is the 2nd biggest part of this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the config library as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration).
Otherwise you can use the npm library [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

In either way what really matters is how you organise your .env files. Env files are supposed to contain database credentials, encryption secret and many confidential data, so its not really a good idea to put them in version control. Instead you should store the .env file in the system. Production server will have .env file with production secrets, developer server can have .env file with local secrets. Flag .env to be ignored by git. In this way you won't have to change according to environment, it will automatically take the right configuration based on which server you are deploying.

Comment: FYI: According to the docs nest-js uses dotenv under the hood

Answer (score 1):

another code style~

if you want to deeply use @nestjs/config , try like this

mkdir  a dictionary named `config`, structure

```
- /config
  - config.default.ts
  - config.dev.ts
  - config.production.ts
  - configuration.ts
```

set individual config in `config.ENV.ts` like this

```
export default {
  // nodemailer config
  mailer: {
    host: 'xxx',
    port: 80,
    auth: {
      user: 'xxx',
      pass: 'xxx',
    },
    secure: false, // or true using 443
  },
  // jwt sign secret
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET || '123456',
  }
}
```

then dynamic exports these file in `configuration.ts`

```
import { merge } from 'lodash';
import DefaultConfig from './config.default';



export default () => {
  let envConfig = {};
  try {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
    envConfig = require(`./config.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`).default;
  } catch (e) {

  }
  
  return merge(DefaultConfig, envConfig);
};
```

import `configuration.ts` in `app.module.ts`

```
import configuration from './config/Configuration';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [configuration],
    }),
  ],
})
```

that's all

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to define custom filename paths for the envFilePath configuration of Netjs's ConfigModule that is based on the environment variable NODE_ENV. You can then set the value of NODE_ENV in your different scripts in your package.json

In your app.module.ts add

```
// Grab the system env variable
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

// Set custom filepath in ConfigModule properties based on NODE_ENV
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
    envFilePath: !ENV ? '.env.dev' : `.env.${ENV}`
    })
  ]
})
```

In your package.json file modify your "scripts" to set NODE_ENV

```
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nest start --watch",
  "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=prod node dist/main"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There are two approaches to this use case.

1.create `.prod.env`, `.development.env`, `.test.env` and load required env like this.

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({envFilePath: '.development.env'});
```

2.create config from function

```
export default () => ({
  port: parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000,
  database: {
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT, 10) || 5432
  }
});
```

and use

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [configuration],
    }),
  ],
})
```

see more [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration)