# nestjs configuration with multiple files

Tags: typescript, config, nestjs, nestjs-config

By default, nestjs uses a config package and wraps it with a high-level abstraction. I have a config folder, with development.ts and production.ts files, and if use config package directly, one of those config file loads by config automatically depends on my env variable value. What are the best practices, to make the same thing but with nestjs configModule?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manage different config environments in nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431679/how-to-manage-different-config-environments-in-nestjs)